# Suppose A is diagonalizable. Can this diagonalization necessarily be done by a matrix P in the special linear group?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, linear-groups

Suppose a square matrix A is diagonalizable. Can this diagonalization necessarily be done by a matrix P with determinant 1?

Comment: Unfortunately, English plays tricks with you rendering the question meaningless: "can necesarily" is nonsensical; do you mean "can it be done" or "is it necessarily so"?

Comment: @AlexM. The question makes perfect sense to me. "can necessarily" means "can always" here; the question is whether or not _all_ diagonalisable $A$ is can be diagonalised using a change of basis with determinant $1$.

Answer (score 6):

Just divide one column of $P$ by its determinant.

This argument shows a more general fact: $SL_n$ acts transitively on each $GL_n$-orbit (if the field is algebraically closed as pointed out in the comments)

Comment: That "more general fact" isn't true.  For instance, if $a$ is not a square, then $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & a \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ are conjugate over $GL_2$ but not over $SL_2$.

Comment: Yes, of course...One needs the field to be algebraically closed for this, sine you cannot multiply only one column. But for orbits with a diagonal matrix, this works over all fields, since $T^{-1}AT$ is diagonal iff $T$ consists of a basis of eigen vectors. An this property is not changed by multiplying only one column.